# How to rename a Key in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am having a `NSMutableDictionary`. I have to dynamically rename any `Key` in the dictionary to a new value, in my code.. I can't find any built-in API to do this..

How can I do this? Is there any built-in API available to do this?

Thanks everyone..

Comment: Is it an option to copy the value out, then create a new key with the desired name?

Comment: I can't directly edit an existing Key?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
// assumes that olkdey and newkey won't be the same; they can't as
// constants... but...
[dict setObject: [dict objectForKey: @"oldkey"] forKey: @"newkey"];
[dict removeObjectForKey: @"oldkey"];
```

---

Think about what "directly editing an existing key" means.  A dictionary is a hash;  it hashes the contents of the keys to find a value.

What happens if you were to change the contents of a key?   The key would need to be rehashed (and the dictionary's internal structures re-balanced) or the value would no longer be retrievable.

Why do you want to edit the contents of a key in the first place?  I.e. what problem does that solve that the above does not?

Comment: Thank you.. This is fine.. I can't directly edit an existing key?

Comment: Mmm.. Nothing specific.. I just expected a direct way to edit the Key.. That's it.. Thanks man..

Comment: Thanks @bbum, this worked for a NSUserdefault as well!

Comment: This fails if `oldkey` equals `newkey`

Comment: @de. In the contrive example, it can't fail because they aren't variables.  But certainly worth noting!

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
- (void) renameKey:(id<NSCopying>)oldKey toKey:(id<NSCopying>)newKey{
    NSObject *object = [dictionary objectForKey:oldKey];
    [object retain];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:oldKey];
    [dictionary setObject:object forKey:newKey];
    [object release];
}
```

This does exactly the same as bbum's answer but, if you remove the old key first (like in this example) then you have to retain the object temporarily otherwise it might get deallocated in the way ;)

Conclusion: Unless you need explicitly to remove the old key first do as bbum.

Comment: This is also significantly more defensive & general purpose; if oldKey and newKey were the same string, it still works (though it does some extra work).

Answer (score 5):

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (KAKeyRenaming)
- (void)ka_replaceKey:(id)oldKey withKey:(id)newKey;
@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (KAKeyRenaming)
- (void)ka_replaceKey:(id)oldKey withKey:(id)newKey
{
    id value = [self objectForKey:oldKey];
    if (value) {
        [self setObject:value forKey:newKey];
        [self removeObjectForKey:oldKey];
    }
}
@end
```

This also handles the case where the dictionary doesn't have a value for the key nicely.

Comment: Another nice solution;  but prefix those methods with something that isn't generic and potentially likely to collide with some future addition to the framework, if there ever was one....

Comment: @bbum is right: prefixing custom classes and protocols should be considered a requirement. Edited for perfection's sake.

Comment: The category name doesn't matter; isn't available at runtime. It is the method names that you have to worry about....

Comment: What is the result when the old and new keys are same. It might sound as a stupid question but unfortunately, I came across a similar situation. The keys are same in few cases, difference in case (upper, lower or combination) of the string. I am getting the keys from server and can't rely that both would be different, and I also the mobile client should be ready to act in such cases too. Please comment if you have a solution to this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have to navigate a complete JSON response object that holds fields, sub-dictionaries and sub-arrays. All because one of the JSON fields is called "return" which is an iOS reserved word, so can't be used with the [JSONModel Cocoa Pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JSONModel).
Here's the code:

```
+ (id) sanitizeJSON:(id) dictIn {
if (dictIn) //check not null
{
    // if it's a dictionary item
    if ([dictIn isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictOut = [dictIn mutableCopy]; 
        // Do the fix replace "return" with "not_return"
        if ([dictOut objectForKey: @"return"])
        {[dictOut setObject: [dictIn objectForKey: @"return"] forKey: @"not_return"];
         [dictOut removeObjectForKey: @"return"];}

        // Continue the recursive walk through
        NSArray*keys=[dictOut allKeys]; //get all the keys
        for (int n=0;n<keys.count;n++)
        {
           NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:n];
           //NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [dictOut objectForKey:key]);
           if (([[dictOut objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) || ([[dictOut objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]))
            {
                // recursive call
                id sanitizedObject =  [self sanitizeJSON:[dictOut objectForKey:key]];
                [dictOut removeObjectForKey: key];
                [dictOut setObject:sanitizedObject forKey:key];
                // replace returned (poss modified) item with this one
            }
        }
        return dictOut; //return dict
    }
    else if ([dictIn isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) //Or if it's an array item
    {

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [dictIn mutableCopy];
        // Do the recursive walk across the array
        for (int n=0;n< tempArray.count; n++)
        {
            // if array item is dictionary
            if (([[tempArray objectAtIndex:n] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) || ([[tempArray objectAtIndex:n] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]))
            {
                // recursive call
                id sanitizedObject =  [self sanitizeJSON:[tempArray objectAtIndex:n]];
                // replace with the possibly modified item
                [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:n withObject:sanitizedObject];
            }
        }
        return tempArray; //return array
    }
    return dictIn; //Not nil or dict or array
}
else
  return dictIn; //return nil 
}
```